# How to remember last read pdf page in web page

Tags: php, pdf, adobe

In my case i want my web application to remember and reload the pdf page that i was reading last when i come to the same page after going to another page. Can this be achieved or if achievable what is the way to do this?

Comment: What have you done so far ? Also elaborate on details like 'how are you identifying a pdf? Do you have a unique id for each pdf etc.'. If you have some pdf identifier , then save the id, last-read-page in database. Anyway, need more details to give an exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sessions to hold the filename/ID and change upon loading a new file

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: I want to redirect user to his last reading page. If he was reading page 152 and he needs to go to another page and come back to the page where pdf file is readable. In this time i should display 152 page to user. This is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess using session ? Set a session variable the first time you read the pdf and then check back if that session variable exists..

```
<?php
   //check if the session variable exists
   session_start();
   if(isset($_SESSION["pdf"])){
     //it exists : do your thing

   }else{
      //set the session variable
      $_SESSION["pdf"] = "mypdf_file.pdf";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution where the user can resume viewing the pdf even after closing the session (i.e closing the browser), then you have two options.

- Set a Cookie - Temporary. Cookies can be cleared and messed with. Read about cookies [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp).
- Save the user credentials (by using a login system etc.) and save the state of the pdf in a database. This is a more permanent solution.

If you want a more temporary solution, you can look at sessions as some of the answers suggested.

```
 session_start();
 if( isset($_SESSION['pdf_name']) ){
       //session variable set. Resume the pdf viewing
 }
 else{ 
     $_SESSION['pdf_name'] = <pdf name>
     $_SESSION['page'] = <page no.>
 }
```

**Note :**  If you need to save the state of multiple pdfs i.e if you want to allow users to resume reading multiple pdf files, then you might need to use the first method.